# How to display tables by school year and semester using php?

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to display a table by school year using PHP. I it seems not working very well because the school year displays redundantly.

How to simply display it like this?

```
No | SY | Student ID | Student Name       | Gender | Section Code |  Subject
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                2015-2016 SEMESTER 1
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  0011941   | Cocos, Scrappy S.  | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  1212211   | asasas, sasas a.  | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                2015-2016 SEMESTER 2
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  0011941   | Cocos, Scrappy S.  | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  aSAsaSA   | dsdsadsad.ssasasas  | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                2016-2017 SEMESTER 1 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  0011941   | Doo, Scooby D.     | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
                                2016-2017 SEMESTER 2 
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1  | 2  |  0011941   | Doo, Scooby D.     | Male   |    IT15B     |  IT15
```

here's my code:

```
 <tr>
        <th>No</th>
        <th>SY</th>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>Gender</th>
        <th>Section Code</th>
        <th>Subject</th>
        <th colspan="2">Update</th>
    </tr>

$sql= "SELECT sts.stud_id, sts.fname, sts.lname, sts.mi, sts.gender, sub.section_code, sub.subject_name, ets.sem, ets.enroll_num, ets.sy
              FROM students sts
              JOIN enrollments ets ON(sts.stud_id = ets.stud_id)
              JOIN subjects sub ON (sub.section_code = ets.section_code)
              GROUP BY sts.stud_id, sub.section_code ORDER BY ets.stud_id ASC";

        $sql_sel=mysql_query($sql); 

        $num_rows = mysql_num_rows($sql_sel);                                                               
            if($num_rows==0)
            {
               echo "No results found. Please try again";
            }

    $i=0;
    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)) //for the first query
    {

        $i++;
        $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
    ?>
        <th colspan="8"><?php echo $row['sy'];?></th>  //this thing here

        <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
            <td><?php echo $i;?></td>

            <td><?php echo $row['sem'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
            <td width="200"><?php echo $row['lname'].", ".$row['fname']." ".$row['mi'].".";?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['section_code'];?></td>
            <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>  
            <td align="center" width="82"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>
            <!----<td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php// echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>-------->
    </tr>
    <?php
    }
    ?>
```

Comment: You would also want to group by year then, And you should not use mysql_* functions since they are not safe and are now deprecated. You should look into PDO and can you provide us your database structure?

Comment: ...or mysqli. And prepared statements

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to order by year and semester in your query:

```
$sql= "SELECT sts.stud_id, sts.fname, sts.lname, sts.mi, sts.gender, sub.section_code, sub.subject_name, ets.sem, ets.enroll_num, ets.sy
              FROM students sts
              JOIN enrollments ets ON(sts.stud_id = ets.stud_id)
              JOIN subjects sub ON (sub.section_code = ets.section_code)
              GROUP BY sts.stud_id, sub.section_code ORDER BY ets.sy ASC, ets.sem ASC, ets.stud_id ASC";
```

Then you only write the year row when you detect a change of year:

```
    $i=0;
    $yr=null;
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($sql_sel)) //for the first query
        {

            if ($yr != ($row['sy'] . ' SEMESTER ' . $row['sem'])) {
               $yr = $row['sy'] . ' SEMESTER ' . $row['sem'];
               print ('<th colspan="8">' . $yr . '</th>');
            }

            $i++;
            $color=($i%2==0)?"lightblue":"white";
        ?>
            <tr bgcolor="<?php echo $color?>">
                <td><?php echo $i;?></td>

                <td><?php echo $row['sem'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['stud_id'];?></td>
                <td width="200"><?php echo $row['lname'].", ".$row['fname']." ".$row['mi'].".";?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['gender'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['section_code'];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $row['subject_name'];?></td>  
                <td align="center" width="82"><a href="?tag=enrollment_entry&opr=upd&rs_id=<?php echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Update"><img src="picture/update.png" /></a></td>
                <!----<td align="center"><a href="?tag=view_enrollments&opr=del&rs_id=<?php// echo $row['enroll_num'];?>" title="Delete"><img src="picture/delete.png" /></a></td>-------->
        </tr>
        <?php
        }
```

Comment: I didn't understand your question.

Comment: Shouldn't you accept the given answer? The rest is just modifying the proposed techinique.

Comment: Your answer is very great and I just want to apply it with semester. Maybe you can make some minor edits, please :).

Comment: Done, but as I said, it is very easy to modify it to include the semester once you know how to do it with the year.

Comment: I already tried but there is a minor mistake in the display after I applied the semester.

Comment: Maybe, but I cannot see it from here

Comment: Done. But remember to also modify the SQL query to sort by semester as well.

Comment: Wow, this is amazing. I thought it's impossible. Can you be my tutor?

Comment: Yeah, $80 an hour. I accept VISA and Mastercard. :)

Comment: I was wondering if you can convert  print (($yr == $row['sy'].' SEMESTER '.$row['sem']) ? '' : '<th colspan="8">' . ($yr = ($row['sy'].' SEMESTER '.$row['sem'])) . '</th>'); into an if statement I find it hard to modify because I'm just a beginner.

Comment: Sir can you explain this print function especially this ? and : how does it work?